# WinUI 3- ; expected error comes after adding C1.WinUI.Grid package in WinUI blank project

Tags: winui-3, componentone, windows-app-sdk

I am new to WinUI 3 Applications.Default blank app works fine. But when I add C1.WinUI.Grid package in project I got below errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package C1.WinUI.Grid 1.4.20233.668 is not compatible with net6.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / win10-arm64. Package C1.WinUI.Grid 1.4.20233.668 supports: net8.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) App1    C:\Users\source\repos\App1\App1.csproj  1   


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: C1.WinUI.Core from 1.4.20233.673 to 1.1.20231.411-preview. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 App1 -> C1.WinUI.Grid 1.4.20233.673 -> C1.WinUI.Core (= 1.4.20233.673) 
 App1 -> C1.WinUI.Core (>= 1.1.20231.411-preview)   App1    C:\Users\source\repos\App1\App1.csproj  1
```

After research I found solution to update the version of C1.WinUI.Core to install C1.WinUI.Grid package. But after adding package I got 816 errors with "; expected"
error for all svg files.

Can someone help to understand how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

- update your project to .NET 8
- update *C1.WinUI.Core* to v1.4.20233.673
- find the missing ';' and add it

otherwise you should ask the package manufacturer for support.